# Is there a recipe available for using jquery, datatables and angularjs with browserify?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, browserify, browserify-shim

I would like to use Datatables with AngularJS using the following directive:

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/

My JS build uses browserify. Would be great if someone could share the recipe/configuration for achieving the integration with Browserify.

Comment: did you manage to find out any solution??